# Brain twister. A simple riddle to play

Tags: riddle, story, liars

You are lost big crowded (monster). There are only two human living Jacobe and Recode . Your task is to reach your home, there are two routes and you are confused.

Conditions: Jacobe always tell the truth and Recode always lie. The thing is you don’t know which one of them is Jacobe.

**Can you ask one question of this man, which calls yes or no answer and find out which is the right path?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya it’s simple 
Putting the following question in past tense would really pay you a answer 
“If I had asked you before! Would you have said that this was a correct path to respective town

Comment: nice twist to the usual solution !! You don't need two characters...

Comment: @phs what . Did you say somthin

Comment: Yes. I like your solution. It works even if only one character is present at the cross-road.

Answer (score 2):

> Ask one of them which path the other one would say was the right path. The truth teller knows the other one lies and would tell you the wrong path and so says the wrong path. The liar knows the truth teller will tell the correct path, and so will lie and tell the wrong path. Either way, go down the path not mentioned. To tune this to your question, ask either if the other would say the left path is the right path. They both say 'no' if it is, and 'yes' if it isn't.